# Java Server to iOS app Stream: Not Correct

Tags: java, ios, networking, stream

I have a Java Server and want to send String messages to a iOS application.

Sending theoretically works, but i always receive "¬í" in my App. I tried different encoding like ASCII, Unicode, UTF-16.

My Java send method looks like this:

```
public void sendName(String str) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Send: "+str);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

and my objective C receive Method looks like this:

```
- (void)readFromStream{
    uint8_t buffer[1024];
    int len;
    NSMutableString *total = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
        len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
        if (len > 0) {
            [total appendString: [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
            NSLog(@"%@",total);
        }
    }
}
```

Does someone know, whats wrong?
Thank you :)

Comment: Do you actually trying to send java object `String` to your iOS app ? That sounds pretty bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `PrintStream` or `BufferedOutputStream` instead of `ObjectOutputStream`. Because `ObjectOutputStream` sounds like you are sending the object `String` instead of just the string.

```
public void sendName(String str) 
{
    PrintStream ps = null;
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("Send: "+str);
        ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ps.println(str);
        ps.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) 
    {
    }
    finally
    {
       if(ps != null)
         ps.close();
    }
}
```

or

```
  public void sendName(String str) 
  {
      BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
      try
      {
          System.out.println("Send: "+str);
          bos = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
          bos.write(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
          bos.flush();
      } catch (IOException ex) 
      {
      }
      finally
      {
          if(bos!= null)
            bos.close();
      }
}
```